# Составить палиндром максимальной длины

Tags: python, строки

Во входном файле записан набор больших латинских букв (не обязательно различных). Разрешается переставлять буквы, а также удалять некоторые буквы. Требуется написать программу, которая из данных букв составит палиндром наибольшей длины, а если таких палиндромов несколько, то можно выводить любой из них.[image: тесты]

Написал такой вот код, но он не проходит все тесты:

```
n = int(input())
str = input()
l = list()
for i in range(len(str)):
    l.insert(i, ord(str[i]))
l = sorted(l)
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = chr(l[i])


    # каждая буква встречается четное количество раз
even = False 
one_even = False
e = l[0]
count = 0
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == e:
        count += 1
    elif count % 2 == 0:
        even = True
        one_even = True
        e = l[i]
        count = 1
    else:
        even = False
        break
    if count % 2 != 0 and i == (len(l) - 1):
        even = False
        
e = l[0]
count = 0
res_str = ""
if even:
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] == e:
            count += 1 
        else:
            res_str += e * int((count / 2))
            count = 1
            e = l[i]
        if i == (len(l) - 1):
            res_str += e * int((count / 2))
    res_str2 = ""
    for i in reversed(res_str):
        res_str2 += i
    print(res_str + res_str2)

    # ни одна буква не встречается четное количество раз
elif not one_even:
    print(l[0])

    # некоторые буквы встречаются нечетное количество раз
else:
    s = set(l)
    s = list(s)
    res_str = ""
    odd = ""
    count = 0
    fiend_Odd = False
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(l)):
            if s[i] == l[j]:
                count += 1
            if j == (len(l) - 1):
                if count % 2 == 0:
                    res_str += s[i] * int(count / 2)
                    count = 0
                elif not fiend_Odd:
                    fiend_Odd = True
                    odd += s[i] * int(count)
                    count = 0
    res_str2 = ""
    for i in reversed(res_str):
        res_str2 += i
    print(res_str + odd + res_str2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил не исправлять ваше решение, а написать своё, если вдруг пригодится. Код выводит ответ в сортированном виде.

Если важно было исправить ваше, то просто мой ответ игнорируйте.

[Пробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##dVLLboQwDLznK@ZSkXSf7F6qlfiF/gDisAtBTaEJIilSVfXbqR3oglrVElI88czYJt1HeHH2PI52C48MxgZpbPcepFKEuD7o6g6Iq/e6D2i1lV4hy0AsSd8EKFHaQBqfX6J2PUoSg78IUJiaUusCQ1Q0gRyU5GVBpKNYpZsMqXBVRfizszrKNVsMM31vgn7zUt21BzzgtIgSwmTjI3vBOSZVyWrqfqFb/6uMG2kK7LiRRY4nWCQr3cY6usyPRTFPX5kyyHlxq15pOx0bJ8n@1RkrGzxCDjgccFL4Zz6FTTSSkwMz4jGlDSFVM/lve3EeJEn0pF3@ePZ60L2nvrr8wr@sU9hBplscVb5aWFEwseen0Ckxjk/ieisrXV9v3w)

```
n, s = int(input()), sorted(input())
assert len(s) == n, (n, len(s))
cnt = {}
for c in s:
    if c not in cnt:
        cnt[c] = 0
    cnt[c] += 1
odd = None
for k, v in cnt.items():
    if v % 2:
        if odd is None:
            odd = (k, v)
        else:
            cnt[k] -= 1
if odd is not None:
    del cnt[odd[0]]
cnt = dict(sorted(cnt.items()))
p = (''.join(k * (v // 2) for k, v in cnt.items()) +
    (odd[0] * ((odd[1] + 1) // 2) if odd is not None else ''))
p += ''.join(reversed(p[:len(p) - (1, 0)[odd is None]]))
print(p)
```

Ввод:

```
8
abcdefab
```

Вывод:

```
abcba
```

Ввод:

```
4
abab
```

Вывод:

```
abba
```

Answer (score 3):

- Подсчитываем количество каждой из букв в строке
- Для букв, количество которых больше 2, добавляем половину в результат
- Вычитаем из счётчиков букв уже использованное количество
- Добавляем в результирующую строку любую оставшуюся букву со счётчиком 1 (если таких нет, то добавляем пусто)
- и дописываем в конец реверснутую результирующую строку (которая на самом деле была половина палиндрома)

```
from collections import Counter

letters = "ABCDABCF"
letters_num = Counter(letters)
result = ""
for letter in letters_num:
    result += letter * (letters_num[letter] // 2)
    letters_num[letter] -= letters_num[letter] // 2 * 2
result += dict(map(reversed, letters_num.items())).get(1,'') + result[::-1]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко:

- Считаем кол-во букв в даной строке. У нас получится примерно такой массив: `[ 'a1', 'b1', 'c0' ]`.
- Для каждой строки, кол-во повторений какой больше 1 добавляем в результат.
- И в конце просто дублируем полученную строку и прибавляем ее в конец.

---

```
s = 'abbca'
a = sorted(list(set(map(lambda x: f'{x}{s.count(x)}', s))), key=lambda x: -int(x[1:]))
for item in a:
    letter, number = item[0], int(item[1:]) // 2
    if number >= 1:
        o += letter * number
    else:
        o += letter
        break

o += o[:-1][::-1] if int(a[-1][1:]) // 2 == 0 else o[::-1]  
print(o) # abcba
```

P.S. Правда если в палиндром будет состоять из цифр, то надо поправить чуть-чуть.

Answer (score 0):

```
def palindrome(letters):
    counter = {}
    single = ''
    result = ''

    for ch in letters:
        if ch not in counter:
            counter[ch] = 1
        else:
            counter[ch] += 1
            if counter[ch] == 2:
                counter[ch] = 0
                result += ch

    for ch, count in counter.items():
        if count == 1:
            single = ch
            break

    return result + single + result[::-1]


print(palindrome('aab'))    # aba
print(palindrome('qazqaz')) # qazzaq
print(palindrome('abcdef')) # a
```